# How to save vector embeddings `FAISS` in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, langchain, faiss, vector-database, similarity-search

I am using LangChain for building some stuff and came across one of the most prominent index-based vector database `FAISS`. Following is the command of how I am using the FAISS vector database:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import PyMuPDFLoader
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS

loader = PyMuPDFLoader('path/to/pdf_file.pdf')
raw_texts = loader.load_and_split()

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(raw_texts, embeddings)
```

In the above code, I want to store the `vectorstore` in a MongoDB database. Is there any way to load these vectorstores on MongoDB and extract them with `similarity_search` with respect to input `prompt`?

Comment: Hey, were you able to do it ?

Comment: Nope. Not yet. Have you got any understanding of how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same situation, by far I found out that we can not save the vector content directly into the Mongo DB but we can expect to save the Index of the FAISS DB.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).